# How to compare and reject arrays items with different dimensions?

Tags: arrays, ruby, match

I have an one dimensional array like so:

```
topics = ["Cats", "Dogs", "Fish", "Snakes"]
```

I also have a multi dimension array, which contains more details of each animal type, but also categorizes them by genus:

```
genus = [["mammals",["Dogs", "Cats", "Tigers"]],
         ["reptiles", ["Snakes", "Lizards"]],
         ["amphibians", ["Fish", "Frogs", "Salamander"]]]
```

What I'm trying to do is compare `topics` to `genus` and revise the `genus` array by removing species that aren't contained in `topics`, but I want to keep the parent genus if it has matched values. If no matched values are found, the entire genus should be deleted from the new array. The end result would be:

```
genus = [["mammals", ["Dogs", "Cats"]],
        ["reptiles",  ["Snakes"]],
        ["amphibians", ["Fish"]]]
```

---

I've tried some approaches by iterating through `topics` and rejecting mismatched species, but it seems to reject *everything* on the first iterations, rendering subsequent iterations pointless.

I've tried `select` and pushing matches to a new array, which got me closer...but it I'd prefer to update the existing array instead of making a new one. (This also didn't account for keeping the genus as part of the array.)

Any help, helps!

What I tried:

```
genus_list = Array.new

topics.each do |topic|
    matched = genus.select { |type, species| species == topic }
    genus_list.push(matched)
end
```

Comment: Please share what you've tried so far

Comment: @hamms I'll put together some sort of examples. The arrays from the question are purely just for example purposes as the real arrays are extremely dense.

Comment: Consider using a hash for `genus`.

Comment: Some sort of dictionary would be a much better data structure in this case.

Comment: Both your before and after `genus` arrays are missing outside braces (`[["mammals.....]]`. Please edit. Birds are mammals?

Comment: @CarySwoveland no, they belong to Aves and I am no longer going to use made up examples ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to me a bit of a brute force approach to the problem, but it's the best I can think of at the current moment. This will modify the `genus` arrays in place

```
# these are as yours in the question, with the addition of a dinosaur genus to show
# that group gets removed from the end result
topics = ["Cats", "Dogs", "Fish", "Snakes"]
genus = [
  ["mammals",
    ["Dogs", "Cats", "Tiger"] ],
  ["reptiles",
    ["Snakes", "Lizards"] ],
  ["amphibians",
    ["Fish", "Frogs", "Salamander"]],
  ["dinosaur",
     ["Tyrannosaurus", "Pterodactyl"]]
]


genus.reject! do |_, animal_types|
  animal_types.reject! { |type| !topics.include?(type) }

  animal_types.empty?
end

p genus
# => [["mammals", ["Dogs", "Cats"]],
#     ["reptiles", ["Snakes"]],
#     ["amphibians", ["Fish"]]]
```

Comment: Winner Winner chicken dinner!

Comment: `_` is just ruby's "unused" variable name...just saying "I'm not using this value so I don't care about", but it also has a special property where you can use it multiple times in a parameter list (for example `def doit(_, _, a)` or `[[1, 2, 3]].each do |_,_, a|` both work while `def doit(a, a, b)` and `[[1, 2, 3]].each do |a, a, b|` throw errors)

Comment: That is pretty rad as I've spent waaaaay too much time trying to think of a variable name that will make sense. Double whammy @SimpleLime

Answer (score 0):

```
topics = ["Cats", "Dogs", "Fish", "Snakes"]

genus = [
  ["mammals", ["Dogs", "Cats", "Birds"]],
  ["reptiles", ["Snakes", "Lizards"]],
  ["amphibians", ["Fish", "Frogs", "Salamander"]],
  ["birds", ["Bluebirds", "Finches"]]
]

genus = genus.each_with_object([]) do |(vertibrate_class, species), arr|
  selective_species = species & topics
  arr << [vertibrate_class, selective_species] unless selective_species.empty?
end
  #=> [["mammals", ["Dogs", "Cats"]],
  #    ["reptiles", ["Snakes"]],
  #    ["amphibians", ["Fish"]]]
```